# C++: how to set object from member?

Tags: c++, class, object, member

I'm pretty new to C++ and I'm trying to make an interactive virtual shop (not like with real money or anything, just something to practice coding, for possible use in a future game). So far I have defined the class and made it so that each object in the class is defined as fruit# where # is its id number (which is used in an array to define its name)
So basically at this point I have created the proper code to turn the user input into the id number of the fruit, but now I need a way to set the values of the fruit "select" to the values of the fruit that id belongs to.
Essentially, they type "banana," which I can use to arrive at the value 0, and the object "fruit0" corresponds to banana. So how do I get from 0 to fruit0? If this is confusing, let me know and I can try to explain better, but I already feel like I'm rambling...

**Here's the (relevant parts of the) code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
const int fruits=6;
//# of fruits
string names[fruits]; 
string s;  

class fruit {
public:
float weight, price;
int id;
string name;
fruit (float a, float b, string c, int d)
{weight = a; price=b; name=c; names[d]=c;}
}; 


int main()
{
fruit fruit0 (.5,1,"banana",0);
fruit fruit1 (1.5,3,"pineapple",1);
fruit fruit2 (2,2.5,"coconut",2);
fruit fruit3 (1,1.5,"papaya",3);
fruit fruit4 (4,2,"watermelon",4);
fruit select (0,0,"\0",fruits);
//other, irrelevant code...
}

void ask()
{
cout<<"What would you like to buy? ";
getline (cin,s);
if (s=="select") {dontsell();}
for (i=0;i<fruits;i++)
{if (s==names[i]){select(i);}}
dontsell();
}

void select(int a)
{
//what goes here???
}
```

Comment: Will an array of `fruit` do the job?

Comment: When you have a series of variables that differ only by a number in their name, you should consider an array instead. In this case however, I would consider `std::map<std::string, fruit>` where the key is the name of the fruit. This will allow you to look up fruits by their name.

Comment: *You can't* access a variable based on its name, but there are other ways to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how to do that. I looked up std::map and I see how I can create a variable that can take the fruit's name as a parameter (maybe the wrong word, but you know what I mean) and return one value associated with it, but how can I use that if I need it associated with 3 or more values? I think an array of fruit may do the trick... maybe

Comment: I ended up adding the following and so far it's working:                           `fruit FRUIT[fruits] = {fruit0,fruit1,fruit2,fruit3,fruit4,select_fruit};`                         I'm using stuff like (FRUIT[a]).name. It's not perfect because I have to add to the array now every time I add a fruit, but it works at least.

Comment: I recommend *against* using `vector` or `map` until you have learned the basics of arrays. And having two names that differ only by case (e.g. `fruit` and `FRUIT`) is a bad habit that will cause you pain later.

Answer (score 0):

#### I suggest you use `std::map<std::string, Fruit>`.

You can use the map for storing fruits and their key phrases. It's sort of like a "codename" structure where one value is always associated with another, such as "Banana" to `fruit1`. Otherwise, I don't really see much of a problem with your question--it's a pretty simple problem which has nice solutions.

You could opt for std::vectors or something, but if you need double vectors that need to be linked by keyword or something, just use std::map.

Comment: _"It's sort of like a "codename" structure"_ - the correct terminology is _associative container_

Answer (score 0):

```
void ask()
{
  cout<<"What would you like to buy? ";
  getline (cin,s);
  if (s=="select") {dontsell();}
  for (i=0;i<fruits;i++)
  {
    if (s==names[i])
    {
      // somehow indicate the selected fruit
    }
  }
  dontsell();
}
```

If I understand correctly, you're asking for advice on how to indicate which fruit object is selected. There are many different ways to do this, but here's one: return the id of the fruit. You also need an array or something to allow you to get the actual fruit object from the id.

```
int ask() {
  // ...
  if (s == names[i]) {
    return i;
  }
  // ...
  // if nothing matches, return nothing:
  return -1;
}

int main() {
  fruit fruit_array[fruits] = {
      fruit(.5, 1, "banana", 0),
      fruit(1.5, 3, "pineapple", 1),
      fruit(2, 2.5, "coconut", 2),
      fruit(1, 1.5, "papaya", 3),
      fruit(4, 2, "watermelon", 4)
  };

  int selected_id = ask();
  if (id > 0) {
    std::cout << "You chose " << fruit_array[selected_id].name << '\n';
  } else {
    std::cout << "You didn't choose anything I recognized.\n";
  }
}
```

Of course, once you do this there are some other changes you would probably want to make. For example there's no reason to have separate arrays `names` and `fruit_array`. Here's an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d84a61293230621) of one way to avoid the duplicate representation of that data.